# Evaluate equation at specific points to create a list of answers

Tags: list-manipulation

A simple question, which I haven't been able to find the answer for:

I wish to evaluate an equation at specific points and create a list of the answers. How can that be done?

**EDIT:**
The reason I ask is because I already have a list of numbers (A), and I need to subtract, element by element, the values in the created list (B), from the values in the one I already have:

```
 A = {0.195775, 0.0704735, 0.0513359, 0.0252646, 0.0563359,-0.014369,-0.00438823, -0.00841716, -0.016843, -0.0433598, "NaN"}

B = {0.344755, 0.327843, 0.176415, 0.0698524, 0.0158143, -0.0129389, -0.0376128, -0.0588051, -0.0578547, -0.018145}
```

Comment: What equation and what points? Can you give an example?

Comment: `Table[f[x], {x, yourlistofpoints}]`? Or `f /@ yourlistofpoints`? More details are needed.

Comment: Also, what do you want to use the list for? To plot it? As a look-up table for future equation solving? Something else?

Comment: After you edit, I am more confused. It seems like your initial question does not fit what you say that you want in your EDIT. Are you simply asking how to subtract one list from another, point by point?

Answer (score 5):

If you are just subtracting one list from another, just do that

```
newList = A-B
```

This will subtract element-by-element like you say you need in your question. Just make sure the lists have the same length (That NaN at the end of A in your example would make this problematic).

Comment: Personally, I'd change that `"NaN"` to something like `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @J.M. I'm just using what is in the OP's post. Tell them that :)